# Python: How do I split a text file and place into VB equivalent of an array?

Tags: python

I have a text file 1.8Mb in size.  It's a data file 1974-present of daily values.  A typical line of data looks like this.

```
 1979      12          5        1.345678     0.1234985     5    0.56342145    Final_value
 1979      12          6        0            0             0    0             Missing_value
 1979      12          7        1.928345     0.4784356     8    1.76942542    Preliminary_value
```

Each day has this same kind of setup to with everything situated into columns.

I want to be able to process the data, taking average values over a period time, graphing the data, etc.  There are two header lines in the text file that would have to be taken off first otherwise all the data looks the same.

What is best way to go about splitting off the data into ??? and then being able to read the separate bits of individual data and work them.  I'm kinda really lost in this situation.  In VB it would be easy but I'm not use enough to Python yet to be able to even figure out what the proper term is to use instead of array.  I want each element to a an 'array' of its own, and each of them is going to have something like 12,000+ elements as of the current date.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Install `pandas`, then simply read the file use `pandas.read_table`:

```
import pandas as pd
data_frame = pd.read_table('test_data.txt', sep='\s+', header=None)
data_frame.columns = ['year', 'month', 'day', 'n1', 'n2', 'n3', 'n4', 'type']
data_frame
```

[image]

As a starting point you might want to try `data_frame.describe()`.

There are many functions to aggregate or summarize the data. For more information [check out the documentation](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/)

Comment: I had seen on a couple of videos about the possibility of pandas or numpy.  One question remains where I'm so use to thinking in Basic sense versus much simpler programming languages...if I want to access the value for something much more recent how do I do it?  In VB it would be something like n1(345) if I wanted to access the data in the 345 position.  Are you suggesting the 'year', 'month', 'day' as being the name of the element and I would still go look at n1(345).

Comment: @confused There are [plenty of methods](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#choice) to access dataframe underlying data in pandas. `year` is merely a column name, you still can access data by column index, row index etc.

Comment: Ok.  After banging my head against a brick wall...I think I might have it figured out...I HOPE!!  I just got to put things in the right order.  This is so much nicer than VB but so different at the same time.  I got to relearn everything.

Comment: This would probably translate into `data_frame.ix[345]` - for more details check the docs http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/indexing.html. Feel free to accept this answer as the correct one (in case it solved your problem ;))